# How do I delay start_response in uwsgi?

Tags: python, wsgi, uwsgi

I want to do the following:

```
r = requests.post('https://foo.com/test', data=json.dumps(fields), headers=headers)
if r.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
    start_response(str(r.status_code) + ' ' + r.reason, [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    body.put(r.reason)
else:
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'application/json')])
    body.put(r.json())
```

But the call would block the main thread, so I do:

```
body = queue.Queue()
gevent.spawn(make_request, environ, start_response, body)
```

but now I get the error `SystemError: you can call uwsgi api function only from the main callable`

So, how do I delay the result of start_response until after the POST request is completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go ahead and block the thread -- just start uWSGI with several of them:

```
uwsgi --http :9090 --wsgi-file foobar.py --master --processes 4 --threads 2
```

from https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#adding-concurrency-and-monitoring